# How to change the header color with App layout of angular components in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-html, dart-webui

How can I change the background color with app layout of angular components in an AngularDart project. I tried it but nothing affected the background blue color.
[image]

layout_component.html

```
<header class="material-header shadow">
<div class="material-header-row">
    <material-button class="material-drawer-button" icon (trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
        <material-icon icon="menu"></material-icon>
    </material-button>
    <span class="material-header-title">Mobile Layout</span>
    <div class="material-spacer"></div>
    <nav class="material-navigation">
        <material-button class="material-drawer-button" icon (trigger)="">
            <material-icon icon="favorite"></material-icon>
        </material-button>
    </nav>
    <nav class="material-navigation">
        <material-button class="material-drawer-button"
                         icon
                         popupSource
                         #source="popupSource"
                         (trigger)="basicPopupVisible = !basicPopupVisible">
            <material-icon icon="more_vert"></material-icon>
        </material-button>
        <material-popup defaultPopupSizeProvider
                        enforceSpaceConstraints
                        [source]="source"
                        [(visible)]="basicPopupVisible">
            <div class="basic">
                Hello, I am a pop up!
            </div>
        </material-popup>
    </nav>
    <nav class="material-navigation">
        <div href="#AppLayout">SIGN IN</div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

layout_component.css

```
.material-header-row {
background-color: black;
}

.basic {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the style to a parent component (`AppComponent`) you can use `::ng-deep` to pierce through component style encapsulation boundaries (from parent into children)

```css
::ng-deep header.material-header {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Or to use your code example

```css
::ng-deep .material-header-row {
  background-color: black;
}
```

**Update**

For above selector, the specificity wasn't high enough to override the background color.

This worked for me:

```css
::ng-deep header.material-header.material-header {
  background-color: black;
}
```

If you add the styles to `index.html`, `::ng-deep` isn't required.

Angular rewrites styles selectors added to components to match the classes like `class="_ngcontent-qbq-3"` it addes to each component (with a different number for each) to enforce style encapsulation.

Styles added to `index.html` are not rewritten and these classes are ignored.

You also might need `::ng-deep` for HTML added with `[innerHTML]="..."` or `someElement.append(...)` because HTML added this way doesn't get the classes added and selectors for CSS added to components will therefore not match after the rewrite anymore.

Comment: how can I fix this Unknown pseudo selector 'ng-deep'

Comment: What do you mean with "fix" or with "unknown"?

Comment: while using it in css I am getting this as an error

Comment: What tool causes this error? (not seeing the error yet). You can try `/deep/` instead. This was changed from `/deep/` to `::ng-deep` not so long ago, because Chrome and SASS dropped support for `/deep/`. `/deep/` should still be supported by Angular if your tools aren't updated yet.

Comment: No not till now, I just need to learn how to implement  ::ng-deep

Comment: There shouldn't be anything to do. Angular removes it and replaces it with `._ngcontent-qbq-3` (or similar). What tool causes the error you mentioned above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153670/discussion-between-tushar-rai-and-gunter-zochbauer).